# GWT: How to handle a generic event fired from a custom widget?

Tags: java, events, generics, gwt

I created a simple custom Widget that contains an HTMLPanel that holds a TextBox and a Button (in a nutshell).

Since I will need this kind of search form more than once, I wanted to make it generic. It works so far, but I don't know how to make the fired event generic.

My Search Widget contains:

```
MyUtils.EVENT_BUS.fireEvent(new SearchEvent(myTextBox.getText()));
```

My Event:

```
    public class SearchEvent extends GwtEvent<SearchEventHandler> {

    public static Type<SearchEventHandler> TYPE = new Type<SearchEventHandler>();
    String toBeSearched;

    public SearchEvent(String aSearchString) {
        toBeSearched = aSearchString;
    }

    public String getToBeSearched() {
        return toBeSearched;
    }

    @Override
    public com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.Type<SearchEventHandler> getAssociatedType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(SearchEventHandler handler) {
        handler.onSearch(this);     
    }
}
```

My EventHandler:

```
    public interface SearchEventHandler extends EventHandler {
    void onSearch(SearchEvent aSearchEvent);
}
```

My problem is that my Widgets sends a specific Event - but I would like to fire another event for another instance of my Widget. So I thought to pass the event through the Contstructor of the Widget (among other parameters I left out here)

```
public SimpleSearch(GwtEvent anEvent) {}
```

And I defined it as a class member of my Widget:

```
private GwtEvent<EventHandler> myEvent;
```

But then, when I try to fire it, I have a Type problem:

```
myEvent = new GenericSearchEvent(myTextBox.getText()); 
MyUtils.EVENT_BUS.fireEvent(myEvent);
```

The Line

```
myEvent = new GenericSearchEvent(myTextBox.getText());
```

does not compile, as Eclipse tells me this:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from SearchEvent to GwtEvent

My question: How to tackle this ?

Cheers,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is why you want to fire different `SearchEvent` for different instances of your Widget ?

If you only want to have different behavior based on which instance of your Widget fired the event,  I would rather encode this directly into your `SearchEvent` class (i.e. add an `enum` or reference to your `sender`/`widget` instance and handle it in the `onSearch` callback):

```
public class SearchEvent extends GwtEvent<SearchEventHandler> {

    public static Type<SearchEventHandler> TYPE = new Type<SearchEventHandler>();
    public static enum TYPE {TYPE1,TYPE2}
    String toBeSearched;
    Widget sender;
    TYPE type;


    public SearchEvent(String aSearchString,Widget sender,TYPE type) {
        toBeSearched = aSearchString;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getToBeSearched() {
        return toBeSearched;
    }

    @Override
    public com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.Type<SearchEventHandler> getAssociatedType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(SearchEventHandler handler) {
        handler.onSearch(this);     
    }
}
```

To your specific problem:
Change the class member in your Widget to `private GwtEvent<? extends EventHandler> event;` and you won't get a compile error.

Comment: Hello, the reason why I want one widget firing different Events is that I want to reuse my search widget. Let's say you have a webpage with different search areas, but the search form itself should look the same. I would then create two instances of my widget, each one firing a different Event (and therefore a different search). I will try your solution and I'll get back to you, thx.